# 2014 Chevy Malibu - Code P055B

Tags: chevrolet, sensor, malibu

I keep getting a P055B code, but I have changed out the sensor twice.  The mechanic cleared the code but it keeps returning.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you also experiencing drivability issues with this? [I found this service bulletin online.](https://static.nhtsa.gov/odi/tsbs/2020/MC-10171292-9999.pdf) which may be of concern. The P055B has to do with the **Cam Position Actuator Oil Pressure Sensor**.

Comment: Yes, it was replaced twice!